# How do I Merge one column's cells if values in another column is same? , My formula isn't working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have values in my excelsheet as such,

```
Data1        Data2

key11        value21
key11        value22
key13        value23
key14        value24
key14        value25
```

And I need the data to be

```
Data1        Data2        

key11        value21 value22     
key13        value23
key14        value24 value25
```

I tried with`C2=IF(A2=A3,B1&B2,B3)`

A column being Data1, and B column being Data2

But even if the values aren't same, am getting b3 being copied to c2.

**There are over 1000+ cells**

Comment: why is it closed?

Comment: Your VBA tag is misleading then. Notice your question never actually has a question

Comment: vba tag just appeared in the suggestion when I typed excel as a tag. I don't even know what's a vba, even if someone posted the vba code, I wouldn't know what to do with it. So again I will have to be searching the forum for it.

Comment: have edited the question.

Comment: @shanganithi you will need `TEXTJOIN()` does your version have that formula?

Comment: A simple fix for your formula should be ```C2=IF(A2=A3,B2&" "&B3,B2)``` but I would recommend a more complex Vlookup or similar

Comment: Your fix works, but I wanted to empty the contents of the cells that have been copied and added to the resulting cell. So I tweaked like this `=IF(A2=A3,B2&" "&B3," ")` , but am getting blanks if values aren't same.

Comment: You can do this pretty simply with `Power Query`.  Merely group by Data1 and then expand the resultant table column.

Answer (score 2):

With TEXTJOIN():

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(A2:A6=C2,B2:B6,""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: hi, I got only zeroes as a result in the resulting column.

Comment: am using Excel 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have posted a VBA solution, here is one using `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+

Once you've set up the query, you can edit your data source and then **refresh** your query to update the results.

- Select a cell in the table
- `Data` --> `Get & Transform` --> `From Table/Range`
- In the PQ Editor:  Select the `Data1` Column and `Group By`

  - Name the resultant column `Grouped`
- Select the resultant table column and

  - Add Custom Column

    - Formula:= Table.Column([Grouped],"Data2")
    - New Column Name `Data2`
  - Select the double-headed arrow on the new Data2 column and

    - Extract Values using the `Comma` delimiter
- Delete the Table Column:

Here is the `M-Code` which you can paste into the Advanced Editor, although you may have to edit the Source line depending on the name of your data table.

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Data1", type text}, {"Data2", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Data1"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Data1=text, Data2=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data2", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Data2")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Data2", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just got help from outside, so thought this will help if anyone else needs it. It is achievable by vba code. Guess I need to learn this stuff soon. Here's the code.

```
Sub ConcatenateCellsIfSameValues()
Dim xCol As New Collection
Dim xSrc As Variant
Dim xRes() As Variant
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim xRg As Range
xSrc = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
Set xRg = Range("D1")
On Error Resume Next
For I = 2 To UBound(xSrc)
    xCol.Add xSrc(I, 1), TypeName(xSrc(I, 1)) & CStr(xSrc(I, 1))
Next I
On Error GoTo 0
ReDim xRes(1 To xCol.Count + 1, 1 To 2)
xRes(1, 1) = "Data1"
xRes(1, 2) = "Data2"
For I = 1 To xCol.Count
    xRes(I + 1, 1) = xCol(I)
    For J = 2 To UBound(xSrc)
        If xSrc(J, 1) = xRes(I + 1, 1) Then
            xRes(I + 1, 2) = xRes(I + 1, 2) & ", " & xSrc(J, 2)
        End If
    Next J
    xRes(I + 1, 2) = Mid(xRes(I + 1, 2), 2)
Next I
Set xRg = xRg.Resize(UBound(xRes, 1), UBound(xRes, 2))
xRg.NumberFormat = "@"
xRg = xRes
xRg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```